# Finding the area between two curves.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area, curves

Context: High School question.

> Find the surface area between the curve of the function $y=6-3x^{2}$
>   and the function $y=3x$ in the interval $[0,2]$

My approach:

-We must find the points of intersection first:

$$6-3x^{2}=3x$$
$$x^{2}+x-2=0$$
$$x=-2,x=1$$

Then we must evaluate these integrals to find the area:

$$A=\left | \int_{0}^{1}(-3x^{2}-3x+6)dx \right |+\left | \int_{1}^{2}(-3x^{2}-3x+6)dx \right |$$

> My question is why couldn't we just evaluate this integral as usual to find the area?

$$\left | \int_{0}^{2}(-3x^{2}-3x+6)dx \right|$$

Comment: The integral $\int_{-1}^1 x \mathrm{d}x$ is equal to $0$ but this is not the area under the curve $y=x$ between $x=-1$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Because the area is the integral of (function which is above) minus (function which is below). In other words, it is equal to$$\int_0^1\lvert6-3x^2-3x\rvert\,\mathrm dx.$$But$$\lvert6-3x^2-3x\rvert=\begin{cases}6-3x^2-3x&\text{ if }x\in[0,1]\\3x-(6-3x^2)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

We want to add up the two pieces of area.

If you integrate them as one term. You are actually computing the difference between the two areas.

\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^2-3x^2+6-3x\, dx\right|&=\left|\int_0^1-3x^2+6-3x\, dx+\int_1^2-3x^2+6-3x\, dx\right|\\
&=\left|\int_0^1-3x^2+6-3x\, dx-\int_1^2 3x-(-3x^2+6)\, dx\right|\\
&=\left|\int_1^2 3x-(-3x^2+6)\, dx-\int_0^1-3x^2+6-3x\, dx\right|\\
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: But why then if we want find the area between two curves like $y=6x-x^{2}$ and $y=x^{2}-2x$ we take the integral without worrying about this, although some parts of the latter function are below the x-axis?

Comment: the important thing is not whether they are above or below the $x$-axis, but whether the relative position of the two curve swaps.

Comment: Could you explain further please.

Comment: the area between two curve between $f$ and $g$ can be obtained via $\int |f-g| \, dx$. To remove the absolute value inside the integral, we can split the integral into the region where $f \ge g$ and the region where $g \ge f$ and then sum them up.  We can't just move the absolute value outside the integral directly.

Comment: why wasn't the absolute value needed for other problems? i.e when should I put it?

Comment: it is needed, just that perhaps you have been very lucky that you didn't encounter problems where the curve intersect and one curve overtake the other.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why is it needed? What is its function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93235/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-positron12).

Answer (score 2):

***Net area*** is shown integrated from difference of two curves$ y_2-y_1=-3x^{2}-3x+6 $  starting at $(0,6)$.

At first the area integal $ -x^3-\dfrac{3 x^2}{2}+6 x $ is positive, maximum at $x=1,$ then at $x\approx 1.81174 $ zero when two areas balance out and thereafter it is negative.

[image]

At $x=2$ net evaluated area is $ A= -2$ shown.

Answer (score 1):

It is $$\int_{-2}^16-3x^2-3xdx$$ the result is given by $$\frac{27}{2}$$ You can add a constant $C$ to both curves and you must not care if the curves are below the axes or not.